# Extracting a matrix of data from a matrix of structs

Tags: matlab, matrix, struct, extract

I have a matrix of structs. I'm trying to extract from that matrix a matrix the same size
with only one of the fields as values.

I've been trying to use struct2cell and similar functions without success.
How can this be done?

Comment: can you add some code here?

Comment: @SamehKamal Jonas code example is what i meant :) Thanks.

Comment: I've uploaded the project to git:
https://github.com/guywald/allele_fixation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you have an array of `struct` like e.g this

```
s(1:2,1:3) = struct('a',1,'b',2);
```

Now you want a different struct that only has the field `b`

```
[newS(1:2,1:3).b] = deal(s.b);
```

**edit**

If all you need is the output (and if the field values are scalar), you can do the following:

```
out = zeros(size(s));
out(:) = cat(1,s.b)
```

Comment: Cool :) This looks great, but i want to final solution to be just a regular matrix with the value, not a struct.

Answer (score 1):

I'll borrow Jonas' example. You can use the `[]` to gather a particular field.

```
% Create structure array
s(1:2,1:3) = struct('a',1,'b',2);

% Change values
for idx = 1:prod(size(s))
    s(idx).a = idx;
    s(idx).b = idx^2;
end

% Gather a specific field and reshape it to the size of the original matrix
A = reshape([s.a],size(s));
B = reshape([s.b],size(s));
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar problem, but the contents of the field in my structure array are varying length strings that I use to tag my data, so when I extract the contents of the field, I want a cell of varying length strings.

This code using [getfield](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/getfield.html) and [arrayfun](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/arrayfun.html) does the job, but I think it is more complicated than it needs to be.

```
sa = struct('name', {'ben' 'frank', 'betty', 'cybil', 'jack'}, 'value', {1 1 2 3 5})
names = arrayfun(@(x) getfield(x, 'name'), sa, 'UniformOutput', false)
```

Can anyone suggest cleaner alternative? [extractfield](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/map/ref/extractfield.html) in the mapping toolbox seems to do the job, but it is not part of the base MATLAB system.

Update: I have answered my own embedded question.

```
names = {sa.name}
```